How to customise the tick marks in jfree chart(i want to skip some points between two tick marks)


DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    dataset.addValue(i, "y.....", "" + i);
}

JFreeChart chart =
        ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                "chart Example",
                "x-axis",
                "y-axis",
                dataset,
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false);
chart.getRenderingHints().put(JFreeChart.KEY_SUPPRESS_SHADOW_GENERATION, Boolean.TRUE);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setItemMargin(0);
renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(.10);
Font font3 = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 5);
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();

for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
    domainAxis.setTickLabelFont("" + j, font3);
}

As you can see in the image x-axis values of jfree chart are not that clear
I'm think of skipping 3-4 points between two tick mark can somebody help me with this??
.

You might look at setCategoryLabelPositions(), for example, or consider an xy bar chart.
